# Broadcast join threshold for number of rows

Tags: apache-spark

I'm in a situation where it seems the table being broadcast is under the threshold for auto broadcast join (so it does broadcast), but the number of rows exceeds the cap which seems to be [~341 million](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/exchange/BroadcastExchangeExec.scala#L115-L125).

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Cannot broadcast the table over 357913941 rows: 412182918 rows
```

This seems to be a hard limitation, but wanted to sanity check if there's some sort of Spark configuration to change this limit, or NOT broadcast based on number of rows to avoid failure.

Basically, is there a row count version of `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold`?